# how can update adapter data list?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have problem with update my data list in recyclerView Adapter,

I am calling webservice to get data list in main.activity like this :

```
private fun get_company_name(){
    val request = buildService(ApiInterface::class.java)
    val call = request.getCompanyList()

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<CompanyModel>>{
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<CompanyModel>>, response: Response<List<CompanyModel>>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful){
                indeterminateBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                frg_holder.apply {
                    setHasFixedSize(true)
                    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
                    adapter = DidebanAdapter(response.body()!!)
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<CompanyModel>>, t: Throwable) {
            indeterminateBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }

    })
}
```

and this is my adapter :

```
class DidebanAdapter(val didebans: List<CompanyModel>): RecyclerView.Adapter<DidebanViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): DidebanViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_dideban, parent, false)
        return DidebanViewHolder(view)
    }



    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return didebans.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DidebanViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.itemView.delete_dideban.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { view ->
            val id : Int = holder.itemView.dideban_id.text.toString().toInt();
            val request = ApiClient.buildService(ApiInterface::class.java)
            val call = request.deleteCompany(id)

            call.enqueue(object : Callback<Boolean> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<Boolean>, response: Response<Boolean>) {
                    notifyItemRemoved(position)
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<Boolean>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.e("msg","false")
                }


            })
        })

        return holder.bind(didebans[position])
    }
}

class DidebanViewHolder(itemView : View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    private val title:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dideban_name)
    private val dideban_id:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dideban_id)

    fun bind(dideban: CompanyModel) {
        title.text = dideban.Title
        dideban_id.text = dideban.Id.toString()
    }

}
```

in onBindViewHolder function i set action for delete images clicked, it calls another webservice and delete item from database, it works correctly, but i want my adapter would update when item was delete.
i use notifyItemRemoved(position), but it cant update my list on demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before `notifyItemRemoved(position)` you should remove element from list manually (adapter wouldn't do that for you) `didebans.remove(position)`

Comment: oh , I can't believe forgot this line, thanks a lot